# Grails noclassDefFoundError Groovy RootLoader

Tags: grails

I'm having an issue using Grails on my machine... Java's installed, Groovy's working, but Grails always fails with a RootLoader class not found issue.

I've tried multiple Java/Groovy/Grails combinations to no effect.

Here's the entire output of my console

```
C:\Users\west>groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.4.3 JVM: 1.7.0_45 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 7

C:\Users\west>grails --version
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/t
ools/RootLoader
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoade
r
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: Do you have the JAVA_HOME specified in your environment variables? Also, did you use the windows installer for Groovy or is this just an un-packaged zip?

Comment: @cjstehno yes i have java_home specified, it's just the un-packaged zip, not the windows installer